# Resetting UIStepper

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel, uistepper

I have a UIStepper set up via IB. It increases and decreases the 'label number' on my view. I'm trying to make a button which when the user presses, will reset the number and UIStepper to zero.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Make a IBOutlet and link it to that stepper, then use whatever method the stepper has to set it to 0 on the press of a button.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to do. I have made a 'reset button' on IB. I can make that to reset the label to 0 but when I press the stepper again, the label will continue from where it was before I pressed the 'reset button'. Is there a bit of code where it will reset the label and stepper? Thanks.

Comment: This is a very simple problem, I pointed you in the right direction, if it's not enough for you to fix it, then you haven't fully understood how this works, and you should focus on that instead,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to add this to your button method

```
yourStepper.value=0;
yourlabel.text=@"0";
```